# Using <style> and <script> in html...is it really so bad?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I really think that it would be beneficial to my workflow if I could just include a fully-functional component with a single php function call. Something like

ddl();

Which would produce an HTML drop down list, fully styled and functional. With external resources, I need to worry about including the JavaScript and CSS to get this working properly, but if I just included all of that within the ddl() function itself, it would make things much easier.

So something like:

```html
<?php
function ddl(){
  <style>
     .ddl{
           //style
      }
  </style>
?>
  <div class="ddl">
     <!-- my drop down list -->
   </div>
   
 <script>
     //Do ddl functionality
 </script>
<?php
}
```

What are the real drawbacks to doing things this way? Is it worse for performance?

Comment: Well every time you decide to use that function you duplicate the CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: You really should consider learning a modern JavaScript framework. Vue's components are basically exactly this, except sanely implemented.

Comment: What if it's only used once or twice per page? Would it make an impact on other pages?

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm thinking of getting into that eventually, but right now I'm using WordPress and it's a big shift to go from php templates to the rest API.

Answer (score 2):

For small projects - one to three pages - you probably won't ever notice much of an issue. Especially if you never duplicate functionality. However, if you want a scalable application, you really need to separate form from function. Style sheets are actually easier to maintain by looking at the relationship of styles amongst themselves. JavaScript is better managed in larger chunks than  embedded scripts.

If you ever decide later to scale an application that has embedded styles and JavaScript, you have the headache to deal with separating these out - especially when you want to reuse functionality. And if you forget to remove a style tag from within your HTML, or worse - a style attribute - it could override your CSS file changes down the road, so the clean-up is really important.

There's also a caching benefit by placing JavaScript and CSS in separate files. When you have a function or a style that's repeated throughout your web app, the browser only has to load the code once per file. If, however, you've embedded it in every page, the browser has to reload all that every time.

For easier maintenance, clarity of code and caching speed, I vote you should always keep these separated from your HTML/PHP.

Answer (score 0):

1. Easier to manage cache, which will reduce bandwidth usage
2. No code duplication
3. Better practice for scalability purposes - maybe you have a interaction designer, graphical designer and a software developer. You wouldn't want everyone to work on the same file

Comment: I now saw there was a better explanation by @Paurian, but maybe this can sum it up a little bit

Comment: I agree with 1 and 2, but for me I disagree with point 3 because it's much clearer to see everything in the one file. I'm the only web developer in charge of the project, too. Is there any way to avoid issues 1 and 2 with this approach?